# New Scribus 1.3.5 (Win): Use tables

Tags: publishing, scribus

I'm using the new Scribus 1.3.5 under Windows. It was never fun to work with tables in it, but now they are literally useless.

My problem: After spanning a table, it seems as if it is only a bunch of grouped text areas. There is no interface to add rows or columns, resize one or the other column, edit the content of a cell and so on.

Am I missing something? Some "double-click on the table while holding Ctrl+Alt+F14" hidden feature? Or a deactivated toolbar? I haven't found any useful documentation on the Scribus website either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've entirely understood the question, mainly use Scribus 1.3.3 but occasionally 1.3.5, both on Ubuntu, so the differences in version and platform may outweigh any similarities but, FWIW, ...

After creating the table it needs to be ungrouped. Text can then be added to individual cells by selecting the cell (e.g. click on the cell). Individual cells can also be resized by selecting the cell and using the frame handles as usual.

A sequence of cells can be selected (select and shift-select each of the cells) and then manipulated together. This can, for example, resize or reposition a whole row or column. Similarly, a column or row of cells, after they are all selected, can be copied and pasted. The new column can have all its cells selected and then slid into position.

Spanning can be achieved manually by deleting a cell then expanding a neighbour.

However, this sounds just like what you don't want - a bunch of grouped text areas.

Anything more complex I import a table constructed elsewhere, not least as I'm no expert in Scribus.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by stating Scribus is a Desktop Publishing program, not a spreadsheet. Use OpenOffice Calc to create your table. Copy and paste it into OO Draw. Now export it to SVG format. Import it into Scribus and you are done!