# Editing groups in Scribus

Tags: publishing, scribus

In Scribus (latest version) is it possible to edit individual elements in a "group" without having to break the group and re-create it from scratch at the end of the edit (and losing any attribute such as the name of the group)?

For example, in Open/LibreOffice Draw it's possible to "enter the context of a group" with a double-click, edit individual components and then exiting the context (clicking outside, AFAIR) and the group is still existing and keeping its features.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/21855/9413) leads me to think it's impossible, but I really miss the reason why creating a table would create a group of text area if the first necessary thing you must do is ungroup them.

PS: this is not a duplicate of that question, as I'm OK with tables being groups of text area, I'm just wondering if groups (tables or whatnot) can be edited without breaking them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Open the Outline Window through Window >> Outline and navigate the tree to the group and the text in the group. When you select it in the tree, you can edit the text in the document.